# Reload one div without reloading the whole page

Tags: jquery, angular, recaptcha

I want to implement localization of reCaptcha widget but the language can only be changed by changing the script src. I have the following done so far:

```
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });

    var language = localStorage.getItem('language');

    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=' + (language === null ? 'hr-HR' : language);

    function writeLanguage(lang) {

        localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
        $("#reCaptchaDiv").load(location.href + " #reCaptchaDiv");

    }
</script>
```

I import the script and set default language if there is no language saved in localStorage. The script src changes once a new language is chosen and saved in localStorage. I want to reload the div without having to reload the whole page and I tried using this:

```
$("#reCaptchaDiv").load(location.href + " #reCaptchaDiv");
```

But after choosing language it doesn't work and the recaptcha widget just disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `load()` doesn't execute any JS in the page, it just retrieves the HTML of the initial page state as a string. Therefore if there is JS in the page that sets the language on load, this is not going to work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so there is no way to reload JS without reloading the whole page?

Comment: Yes, but not in the way that you need. If you want it to work like this you'll need to move the logic which determines the language to the server side